# NSPredicate Whitespace ignore in string

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I have below code that has validation of string but in **fourth character** i want to ignore any white space entered by user and accordingly the length of string increased by one character.

```
- (BOOL)validatePancard:(NSString *)candidate
{
    NSString *panCardRegex = @"[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", panCardRegex];
    NSLog(@"valid : %d", [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate]);
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[A-Z]{3}( ){0,1}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}`? That's what you mean? It's not the "best looking" regex, but it's explicit and match the style you applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Implement Below code it works.

```
BOOL isValid = [self validatePancard:@"ABC 5ZEXZ TRE"];


- (BOOL)validatePancard:(NSString *)candidate
{
    NSMutableString *a = [NSMutableString stringWithString:candidate];
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 3; //Remove Character at forth position
    range.length = 1; // number of character you want to remove
    [a deleteCharactersInRange:range];

    NSString *strImmutableString = [NSString stringWithString:a];

    NSString *panCardRegex = @"[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", panCardRegex];
    NSLog(@"valid : %d", [emailTest evaluateWithObject:strImmutableString]);
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//You Can Use Any One OF them   :-

```
////1)

NSString *YourOldString = @"Please    Don't Kill        Me";

NSString *NewString = [YourOldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s" withString:@""  options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [YourOldString length])];

NSLog(@"Your New String is %@",NewString);

//2).
NSArray* YourArray = [YourOldString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSString* StringWithSpcs = [YourArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"The String is %@",StringWithSpcs);

//Or

//3).to remove only a given character from your string Use This

[YourOldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```